# What should we do regarding the php tag?

Tags: discussion

As stated in its description https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php the PHP tag is obsolete.

But as you can see there's still 1000+ questions tagged with it.

What can we do about that ? 
Should we remove the tag from every question tagged with it ?

Deleting the tag would be worse as I'm sure a lot of people will recreate it and the "obsolete" description will be gone, it would probably make it worse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say, leave it. Manually burninating it is not worth the trouble and letting the moderators do it won't help much as you already noticed.

I don't think it does any harm and don't even agree 100% with the "obsolete" description. Remember that tag descriptions often represent the opinion of the first user who created it and are open to discussion and change.

Some, like Alan Storm, add the tag to all coding related questions to separate them from questions about for example JavaScript, layout XML, or store configuration. Most don't because it seems obvious and you only have 5 tags per question, where one should be used for the Magento version.

So in my opinion, while the programming language is not a **necessary** tag on this site, I don't see a reason to disallow it and [php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) is as valid as [javascript](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Comment: Well I was about to get on a solo MageStackDay for those ^^

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism There are better targets for that. I'm already gathering a tags-to-kill list for the next MSD with gems like `edit` and `data`

Comment: I full agree to @fschmengler ... The last paragraph is imho the most important. As long as javascript is a valid tag, php should be too. For sure most questions will be PHP related but not only as stated out too.

Comment: On that note, wouldn't it make more sense for us to require the user to specify a magento version in their tags before allowing them to post a question? I'm not sure if this can be done, but if it could, it'd make sense to do it - I had several questions scrapped when I just started asking magento questions because I had neglected to include a version tag.

Answer (score 4):

What we should do about this tag, is thinking about its usecase and properly use it for this.

as a first step for this I changed the excerpt to

> This tag is used for questions which involve PHP code in any way. So
>   as soon there is an php Exception returned or error report generated,
>   this question qualifies to be tagged with PHP.

still in review, but probably a more usefull solution then just removing all the php tags.

I also added a bit of excerpt to the php-7 tag

Comment: Yep I approved your excerpt, maybe you should improve the tag body instead of fully removing the old deprecated content.

Comment: added a hopefully helpfull body